# Ionic/angular ios purchase

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

i know there have been several similar or identical topics, but I just want to verify that this is indeed the case and nothing has changed.

If I want to test payments in the application, I have to submit them -> not have payments in the ready to submit state.

Which means for me to submit an application to the app store based on this report: Your first in-app purchase must be submitted with a new app version. Create your in-app purchase, then select it from the app’s In-App Purchases section under App Store and click Submit. Learn More

I am attaching the image -> [image]

Thnank you guys for any help, explenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test payments in the application, you can already do it by publishing your binary on testflight. All in-app purchases will be performed in sandbox mode, and you will be able to make purchases without paying with "real" money.

As shown on your screen, your 2 in app purchases are ready to submit. It means that on the next binary submission you will make, you will be able to select these purchases, which will be verified with your app.